# How to extract all keys with a prefix in Couchbase

Tags: c#, couchbase

I want to delete all the documents with a prefix. For example, all the documents with documentIds starting with name lets say `Identifier1`.

I've found [this](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-delete-multiple-couchbase-entities-having-common-key-pattern/4151/2) article which does this using NodeJS. I'm not able to convert this code to equivalent C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Couchbase 4.x, then in addition to what Simon suggested in his answer, you can use N1QL to delete documents with a simple query.

First, if you haven't used N1QL before, make sure you have a primary index on the bucket by running the following query once:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON <bucket> USING GSI;
```

You can use the command-line query tool (located in `/opt/couchbase/bin/cbq`) or, if using Couchbase 4.5+, the Query Workbench in the UI.

Then, to delete all document by an ID prefix, use the following command:

```
DELETE FROM <bucket> WHERE meta().id LIKE '<prefix>%';
```

Again, you can use the command-line tool, the Query Workbench, or do this programmatically, which will look something like the following in C#:

```
var result = await bucket.QueryAsync("<query>");
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# the range is expressed as a `StartKey` and `EndKey`.

First *on the server side* the view must be created and published to production:

```
function(doc, meta) {
    emit(meta.id, null);
}
```

Then *on the client side* use a `ViewQuery` object with a `StartKey` and `EndKey`:

```
var prefix = "pre_"; //this should be a parameter of your method
var query = ViewQuery.From("designDocumentName", "viewName");
query.StartKey(prefix);
query.EndKey(prefix + "\u0000");
```

Then execute the query using the `Bucket`'s `Query(ViewQuery)` method.